# Spamassassin: Is it possible to write spam addresses to an external file?

Tags: spamassasin

I'm am running Spamassassin v3.3.1 on CentOS.

I'm trying to find a way of writing the "From" header (the from address) for emails which have been identified as spam to an external file.

The idea being that I want to create a blacklist of addresses based on this content.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server should log the message rejection along with the source IP address.  You can mine this data to build your blacklist.

The `Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::AWL` plugin records spam scores in a database.  If you set the mask bits to record the full IP address, you can extract the IP addresses for generating a blacklist.

You may want to combine this with a whitelist so you don't blacklist servers from major free-mail sites.